# using perl cgi to fetch cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, cgi

I'm trying to inspect cookie values in a cgi script; my test script looks like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use DBI;
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use CGI::Cookie;

my $cgiH = CGI->new;

print header;
print start_html(-title=>'Cookie Terms'), h1("Cookie Terms"), "<hr>\n";

%cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
foreach $k (keys %cookies) {
    my $term = "$cookies{$k}";
    my $term =~ s/SubjectTerm//;
    print "at $k is $term \n";
}

print end_html;
```

the relevant input to the script (from an HTTP GET) is

```
Cookie: SubjectTerm1=ponies
Cookie: SubjectTerm2=horses
```

(this is verified by using either fiddler or debugging the code in my delphi app). the result of my script (omitting the HTML wrapper) is either

```
at SubjectTerm1 is  
at SubjectTerm2 is
```

or if I change the print statement to

```
print "at $k is $cookies{$k}\n";
```

it is

```
at SubjectTerm1 is SubjectTerm1=ponies; path=/
at SubjectTerm2 is SubjectTerm2=horses; path=/
```

What I want to arrive it is something like this

```
at SubjectTerm1 is ponies
at SubjectTerm2 is horses
```

I know I'm missing something about the hash usage but can't quite figure out what it is.
am I not addressing the %cookies hash correctly?

Answer (score 5):

If you had `use warnings` you would see you are clobbering the `$term` with the line

```
my $term =~ s/SubjectTerm//;
```

Remove the `my`.

I think you might be able to extract the value is simply changing the assignment to

```
my $term = $cookies{$k}->value();
```

and get rid of the `s/SubjectTerm//`. But not sure about this sorry.

Comment: thank you for the answer (both of them!). blushing at the double 'my'; and the $cookies{$k}->value tip works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, before I answer the question, I'd strongly recommend you look at using something other than CGI.pm -- it's the best of late-90s Perl, and other than being included by default in the core perl distribution has little to recommend it.

Some more modern, more featureful alternatives include:

- CGI::Application - http://cgi-app.org/
- Mojolicious - http://mojolicio.us/
- Dancer - http://www.perldancer.org/

Beyond that, as @Sodved says if you'd included `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your file the first of your problems -- clobbering $term by using `my` twice -- would have been highlighted immediately.

Once you're using the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas (and I'd say, don't leave home without them) you'll also want to change your foreach to either:

```
foreach (keys %cookies) {
    my $term = $cookies{$_};
...
```

OR

```
foreach my $k (keys %cookies) {
    my $term = $cookies{$k};
...
```

That is, you'll either need to declare the $k variable, or you may prefer to use Perl's built-in `$_` inside the loop -- it's purely a matter of style.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks. fwiw i'm coming back to perl after a long hiatus; my last perl app of any size about 15 years back now.

Comment: Yeah that's prime CGI era :-) Perl's grown up a lot since then! If you're interested, the big things you might want to look at: replacing DBI with DBIx::Class, using the decent modern OO tools like Moo/Moose, and the web frameworks large and small that have sprung up to replace CGI.pm